# Wait for DOM element then react - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have a class component as shown below:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
       const divElement = document.getElementbyId('id'); // this element could take a few seconds to load
       if (props.something1 && props.something2) {
          ..do something with divElement's width
       }
    }
    render() {
      return ....
    }
}
```

I want to wait until divElement is loaded, or trigger an event when divElement is loaded so I can do my calculation later, tried adding setTimeout which did not work

Comment: Is the element you're waiting for rendered by the component, or completely outside the React part of your page?

Comment: have you tried using  `ref` in React.

Comment: *"...tried adding setTimeout which did not work..."* What did that look like? That's certainly one way to address it.

Comment: Just noticed an error in your code snippet, you need to put `divElement` in your if block as well. `if (props.something1 && props.something2 && divElement)`

Answer (score 15):

Two answers for you:

### Use a ref (if your component renders the element)

If the element is rendered by your component, use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

### Use a `MutationObserver` (if the element is outside React)

If the element is completely outside the React part of your page, I'd look for it with `getElementById` as you are, and if you don't find it, use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to wait for it to be added. Don't forget to remove the mutation observer in [`componentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount).

That would look something like this:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   const divElement = document.getElementbyId('id');
   if (divElement) {
      this.doStuffWith(divElement);
   } else {
      this.observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
         const divElement = document.getElementbyId('id');
         if (divElement) {
            this.removeObserver();
            this.doStuffWith(divElement);
         }
      });
      this.observer.observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
   }
}
componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.removeObserver();
}
removeObserver = () => {
    if (this.observer) {
        this.observer.disconnect();
        this.observer = null;
    }
}
```

(You may have to tweak that, it's off-the-cuff; see the `MutationObserver` documentation for details.)

Answer (score 11):

This is a dumb solution but it gets its jobs done:

```js
const getElementByIdAsync = id => new Promise(resolve => {
  const getElement = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById(id);
    if(element) {
      resolve(element);
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(getElement);
    }
  };
  getElement();
});
```

To use it:

```js
componentDidMount = async () => {
  const divElement = await getElementByIdAsync('id');
  if (props.something1 && props.something2) {
    // ..do something with divElement's width
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is rather brilliant. I would like see if there are any arguments for downsides to using this method.

Comment: Very obviously performance and thread blocking... @Onat

Comment: @NoraSöderlund Performance, maybe not the best. But how would an async function be thread blocking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `componentDidUpdate` hook instead of `componentDidMount` hook. And better to use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) rather than getting div element by it's id:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (props.something1 && props.something2) {
    // use divElementRef to interact with
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @hao-wu is great. Just if anyone wonders how to use it with hooks here is my snippet.

```
const Editor = () => {
  const [editor, setEditor] = useState<SimpleMDE | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const initialOptions = {
        element: await getElementByIdAsync(id),
        initialValue: currentValueRef.current
      };
      setEditor(
        new SimpleMDE({
          element: await getElementByIdAsync(id),
          initialValue: currentValueRef.current
        })
      );
    })();
  }, [id]);

  // Other effects that are looking for `editor` instance

  return <textarea id={id} />;
};
```

Otherwise, the constructor of SimpleMDE cannot find an element and everything is broken :)
I guess you can adjust it to your use-case quite easily.

Most of the time `useRef` just works, but not in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my hook version to @hao-wu's answer

```js
const useGetElementAsync = (query) => {
  const [element, setElement] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let element = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        function getElement() {
          const element = document.querySelector(query);
          if (element) {
            resolve(element);
          } else {
            console.count();
            // Set timeout isn't a must but it
            // decreases number of recursions
            setTimeout(() => {
              requestAnimationFrame(getElement);
            }, 100);
          }
        };

        getElement();
      });

      setElement(element);
    })();
  }, [query]);

  return element;
};
```

To use it:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(true);
  const element = useGetElementAsync(".myElement");

  // This is to simulate element loading at a later time
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsHidden(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {!isHidden && (
        <h2 className="myElement">My tag name is {element?.tagName}</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/usegetelementasync-utcb9m)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like;

```js
componentDidMount() {
  // Triggering load of some element
  document.querySelector("#id").onload = function() {
    // Write your code logic here
    // code here ..
  }
}
```

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: If the element isn't there for the OP's `getElementById('id')` call, it's not going to be there for your `querySelector("#id")`, so `querySelector` will return `null` and your code will throw an error.